# Performance Issue - AppRedirect.aspx taking long time to redirect to Provider Hosted App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

We have a SharePoint 2013 environment with Provider Hosted App.

In TEST environment, SharePoint is able to redirect to Provider Hosted App (via `AppRedirect.aspx`) in milliseconds.

However in Staging/Production environment, same activity is taking 15-25 seconds.

We are facing this issue in only one SharePoint web-application.

Any reason for this performance issue during AppRedirect?

Edit - Attaching screenshot of network traffic

[image: Network Trace]

Comment: Using SSL? Host headers in the web applications?

Comment: Yes, we are using SSL. We are also using host headers in the web application. However similar web-application in same farm (SSL + host header) is not having this issue.

Comment: Can you try to capture the network traffic using fiddler or F12 developer tools in any browser? This should help you to see what's taking so long.

Comment: I have added the network traffic screenshot in the original question. Maximum time is spent at AppRedirect when SharePoint is trying to redirect from SharePoint site to ProviderHostedApp

Comment: Can you check your Event Viewer on all servers if there is any issue in the Certificate Validation. It is possible that Certificate Validation is slowing down the page load.

Comment: @TempaC - Thanks for the tip regarding certificate validation check. Any idea how to verify if 'certificate validation check' is taking time. Will Fiddler help here? (Note - We are not able to find anything on this front in IE F12 Developer tools)

Comment: @xs2mayank Regarding the certificate validation event. Check if you can find Event 8321 (A certificate validation operation took X milliseconds and has exceeded the execution time threshold) in your event viewer. If it appears, it should be occurring quite often.

Comment: @TempaC - Thanks for the tip. We checked for the event but were not able to find anything. However the issue got resolved automatically and AppRedirect is working fine now without any problem. Not sure if there was some environment problem (Hardware/SharePoint KB update) which might be causing the issue.